I am under heavy DoS attack - How can I block attacker ip's
I am under heavy DoS attack since 3 days and now I upgrade my CloudFlare account to premium. Now I know attacker ip's how can I block all of them in my ubuntu server 22.04?
Attacks coming from IPV4 & IPV6 ip's. I cant block them in CloudFlare because of I don't have a business plan, My blocking options are only business accounts.
Here is a screenshot:


The first D of DDoS stands for Distributed. If it comes from one IP address, it is not distributed. If it is one IP address, a firewall rule should suffice. Try sudo ufw deny from 27.59.108.21 to any to block this IP address.

This question is similar to: How to ban an IP temporarily after several incorrect password attempts?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


You can block any IP with this command:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s <malicious-IP> -j DROP

You can unblock it with:
sudo iptables -D INPUT -s <malicious-IP> -j DROP


You can also setup a rate limit.
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m limit --limit 10/min --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT \
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP \



-A INPUT: Appends the rule to the INPUT chain. 
-p tcp: Applies the rule to TCP traffic. 
--dport 80: Specifies the port to which the rule applies (e.g., 80 for HTTP). 
-s 192.168.1.0/24: Specifies the source IP range in CIDR notation. 
-m limit: Uses the limit module to control traffic. 
--limit 10/min: Allows a maximum of 10 packets per minute. 
--limit-burst 20: Allows up to 20 packets initially (burst) before rate limiting applies. 
-j ACCEPT: Accepts packets matching the limit criteria. 
-j DROP: Drops packets exceeding the limit. \
